# Missing "en" locale

Tags: opensuse, locale

I'm on openSUSE Tumbleweed, and I'm trying to universally change my time to 24-hour format. Mostly for the KDE lock screen, but also other things.

My first attempt was to set RC_LC_TIME="en_GB" in /etc/sysconfig/language (via YaST), not realizing that "TIME" also affected the date, so now my date field in Thunderbird is DD/MM/YYYY, which is disorienting.

Next I tried looping through all my locales to see what other options might work:

```
cd /usr/share/locale
for f in *; do echo -e "$f\t$(LC_TIME=$f date +"%A %B %c")";done | grep "Tuesday December Tue Dec" | grep -v "[AP]M" | less
```

That gave me lots of options, the most obvious of which was "en." So I tried that, but now I get the following error on login:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en)
/usr/bin/manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

So before I go down the locale list trial-and-erroring to see what works, what's the correct approach here? I just want en_US but with 24-hour time.

Comment: Can you not, once logged in, RH mouse click on the time, choose `set time format`, then in the window go `detailed settings->Time format` as a start?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did that, but it only affects the panel clock. I'm trying to set the option system-wide for the lock screen, file timestamps, mail headers, etc. But I think I found a viable solution and am about to edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`en` is not a locale name. Not all directories in `/usr/share/locales` are locale names. Some contain data that is shared by multiple locales. For example, `en` contains files used by all variants English language.

Most locale name have the form `language_REGION`, for example `en_US` (US English), `en_GB` (UK English), `en_CA` (Canadian English), etc.

To get the list of locales that are available on your (Glibc-based, i.e. non-embedded Linux) system, run

```
locale -a
```

On some systems (at least on Debian and derivatives), not all locales are ready for use by default. `locale -a` only lists locales that are ready for use. The full list of locales is available in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`. If you want to make a locale ready, run `locale.gen`. (Check the man page on your system: different versions have different syntax.)

You can search through available locales for one that has the properties you want. Information about locales is in files in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/`. You want one where the default date format has `%m` before `%d`, and where the default time format has 24-hour time, and where the weekday names are in English. Here's a script that searches through available locales and reports those with a month-before-day date and English weekdays.

```
for x in /usr/share/i18n/locales/*; do
  awk '
    $1=="t_fmt" {t = $0}
    $1 == "d_fmt" && /%m.*%d/ {mdy=1}
    $1=="day" && (/Sunday/ || /Monday/) {english=1}
    END {if (english && mdy) {print FILENAME, t}}
  ' $x;
done
```

Output on my system:

```
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_CA t_fmt       "%r"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_DK t_fmt    "%T"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US t_fmt   "%r"
```

`%r` is 12-hour time, `%T` is 24-hour time. So the `en_DK` locale has the properties you want. You may want to specify a text encoding, probably `en_DK.UTF-8`.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, because it's GREAT info! But one minor nitpick is that en_DK uses a dot for the time delimiter instead of a colon. As I mentioned in my answer, I tried C.UTF8, but that one shows seconds on the KDE lockscreen, oddly. It's crazy that this is not straightforward.

Comment: Ok, so en_DK still shows timestamps in Thunderbird as `DD/MM/YYYY HH.MM`, whereas C.UTF8 is `MM/DD/YY HH:MM`. The only oddity I've noticed about C.UTF8 so far is the `:SS` on the lockscreen. That's not necessarily bad, just odd.

Answer (score 0):

After additional troubleshooting, I realized that `ls /usr/share/locale` is not what I should have been testing, but rather `$(localectl list-locales)`. Running the same loop gave me a single answer: **C.UTF8**. As far as I can tell, that's working as I hoped.

But I'm still wondering if this is the best approach.